# Datatable double-click event : issue while trying to display reactive values within modalDialog (Rshiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to display a range of reactive values within a modalDialog based on double-click event in a datatable.

What I did so far (reproducible example):

```
ui <-fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("test"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      data = iris, 
      class = 'compact',
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      selection = "single",
      options = (
        list(
          dom = "t",
          ordering = FALSE,
          paging = FALSE,
          autoWidth = FALSE,
          scrollY = "100vh",
          scrollCollapse = FALSE
        )
      ),
      callback = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "table.on('dblclick', 'td',", 
        "  function() {",
        "    var row = table.cell(this).index().row;",
        "    var col = table.cell(this).index().column;",
        "    Shiny.setInputValue('dt_dblclick', {dt_row: row, dt_col: col});",
        "  }",
        ");"
      )
    ) 
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  
  
  modal_content <- reactive(paste(
    '<figure class="snip0056 yellow">
    <figcaption>
      <h5 style="color:black;font-size:3rem"><b> Flower name:', iris$Species[input$test_rows_selected], '</b></h5>
      <h2 style="color:#7C8386;font-size:2.5rem"><b> Petal Width', iris$Species[input$test_rows_selected], '</b></h2>
    <h5 style="color:#3ba51a;font-size:2rem;padding-top: 10px;">Keywords: </b></h5></i>',
    checkboxGroupButtons(
      inputId = "domaines_tags",
      label = "",
      choices = c(unique(iris$Species[input$test_rows_selected])),
      selected = NULL
    ),
    '<div class="icons"><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-home"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-email"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i></a></div>
    </figcaption><img src="https://u.cubeupload.com/adsuri/7NQDHz.jpeg" alt="sample9" width="10"/>'))

  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$dt_dblclick, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Popup test",
        HTML(modal_content()),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Annuler")
        ),  size = "l"
      ))
    })
  
  
}
```

As you can see the reactive values are not displayed in the modal window but if I change       `observeEvent(input$dt_dblclick, {` by `observeEvent(input$test_rows_selected, {` the code works perfectly fine ! What am I missing ?

Comment: It works but there's a conflict between the click to select and the double click. I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thanks for your reply ! 
Since I'm already using ```observeEvent(input$test_rows_selected, {``` to trigger an action I would like to use the ```observeEvent(input$dt_dblclick, {``` for another action (opening a modalDialog for instance) and I thought it would be the best option.
Is there no way to resolve this conflict ?

Comment: Maybe you can attach the double-click event on the table header instead of the table cells?

Comment: What do you mean ? I need to retrieve informations associated with the selected row so I don't get why should I use the table header ?

Comment: So why don't you use `input$test_rows_selected`? Why do you want the double click?

Comment: Because I'm already using ```input$test_rows_selected``` for another specific action...